# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'logo' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert a photo into a BLOB column of a MySQL table, and I get an exception:

```
Data too long for column 'logo' at row 1.
```

Here is the JDBC:

```
    int idRestaurant = 42;
    String restoname=  "test";
    String restostatus=  "test";
    InputStream fileContent = getUploadedFile();
    int fileSize = getUploadedFileSize();

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resto" , "root" , "" )) {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into restaurants (idRestaurant, restaurantName, status, logo) values(?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1, idRestaurant);
        ps.setString(2, restoname);
        ps.setString(3, restostatus);
        ps.setBinaryStream(4, fileContent, fileSize);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    }
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You have three choices to fix this.   1. Increase the size of your column datatype.  2. Decrease the size of the content being inserted into that column.  3. Don't insert the information.

Comment: Make sure you don't have trigger on your table.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You are trying to insert data that is larger than allowed for the column `logo`.

Use following data types as per your need

```
TINYBLOB   :     maximum length of 255 bytes  
BLOB       :     maximum length of 65,535 bytes  
MEDIUMBLOB :     maximum length of 16,777,215 bytes  
LONGBLOB   :     maximum length of 4,294,967,295 bytes
```

Use `LONGBLOB` to avoid this exception.

Comment: I have a VARCHAR field with length 50 and this string 'amsterdam 12234 2^)(&*||' is giving me the same error even when its length is less than 50. Are there any restrictions on the data format too?

Answer (score 13):

Use data type `LONGBLOB` instead of `BLOB` in your database table.

Answer (score 8):

Following solution worked for me. When connecting to the db, specify that data should be truncated if they are too long (jdbcCompliantTruncation). My link looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://SERVER:PORT_NO/SCHEMA?sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
```

If you increase the size of the strings, you may face the same problem in future if the string you are attempting to store into the DB is longer than the new size.

EDIT: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES has to be removed from sql_mode as well.

Comment: This part "jdbcCompliantTruncation=false" is what I actually needed, cuz  first I had removed STRICT_TRANS_TABLES and that had had no effect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

*String*, in general, should be used for short text. By default, it is a `VARCHAR(255)`

**Solution:**
In The entity use annotation @Column with length.

Exemple:

```
@Entity
public class Users {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
     private String email;
     //..
     @Column(length = 1000) //1000 will be fine
     private String imgProfile;
}
```