# javafx quality of the images uploaded

Tags: mysql, eclipse, javafx, phpmyadmin

my application connects to a database in mysql using phpmyadmin and stores an image in the database, but my problem is when I download the image from the database and post the image on a imageview the image has a very low quality where also it's color is being afected too.

if I post the image directly on the database using phpmyadmin and then download the image using my app the image looks fine, but if I upload the image from my app and then i download it then the quality is bad.

the way to post the image is past the image to a byte[] and then uploading to the database that uses the type blob.

```
private byte[] imagenToByte(Image imagen) {
    BufferedImage bufferimage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imagen, null);
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
        ImageIO.write(bufferimage, "jpg", output );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      byte [] data = output.toByteArray();
      return data;
}
```

can you help me please?

EDIT

```
@FXML
public void eventoBotonSeleccionarImagen() {
    FileChooser imagenSeleccionada = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filtroImagenjpg = new ExtensionFilter("Archivos *.jpg", "*.jpg");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filtroImagenJPG = new ExtensionFilter("Archivos *.JPG", "*.JPG");

    File archivo = imagenSeleccionada.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(archivo);
        Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
        imageViewMonstruo.setImage(image);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How to you load/create the original image (`Image` object)? Why do you use JPEG and not e.g. PNG?

Comment: Look at the edit, the purpose is to select the image from the pc, I use jpg because the images are in jpg, and it works, but the image uploaded has a low quality with it's colors being afected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question thanks to this
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522875/data-truncation-data-too-long-for-column-logo-at-row-1).

What I've done is changing from Blob to longblob in the database and adding png instead of jpg, the code result is this

```
private byte[] imagenToByte(Image imagen) {
    BufferedImage bufferimage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imagen, null);
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
        ImageIO.write(bufferimage, "png", output );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      byte [] data = output.toByteArray();
      return data;
}
```

And finally it upload and download the images with the same quality